# Calculating Birthday into year month day hours minutes and seconds

Tags: php, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Can someone show me code for calculating a birthday into a year month day hours minutes and seconds

Example : `Aug 8, 1993`

The expected result would be like this :

As of `Dec 16, 2012 11:04`
Your age is `19 years 4 months 12 days 11 hours 4 minutes and 23 seconds`

Comment: in which language you prefer?

Comment: @Kasun it's tagged as PHP. mkdate and date are your friends

Comment: opps, sorry about the silly mistake

Comment: okay thanks a lot Kasun... 

hakre yeah ! Sorry about that i wasn't able to find that one earlier

Comment: @cathe: Search harder. Any possible date-time related PHP question has been asked and answered already.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    <?php 
       $birthday = new DateTime("2007-03-24");
       $today = new DateTime();
       $interval = $birthday->diff($today);
       echo "difference " . $interval->y . " years, " . $interval->m." months, ".$interval->d." days ";     
    ?>
```

[How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: @Kasum: Please don't copy answers, especially as this question is a duplicate. Leave a link as a comment below the question itself to the answer instead.

Comment: i have added link also and modified to match @cathe's requirement

Comment: @hakre I read on meta that you like to close questions, but what is wrong with copying the relevant parts? I personally hate it to follow dozens of redirects.

Comment: @rekire: That is why it is important to not duplicate content too much. That not only keeps redirects low, it also allows to locate the information more quickly on the site. Closing is very helpful in that case, duplicating content not.